# play 2.2.1 - startup (Dev mode) - Attempting to obtain a connection from a pool that has already been shutdown

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, akka, playframework-2.2

I need help with below exception on app startup (Play 2.2.1/Java):
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: java.sql.SQLException: Attempting to obtain a connection from a pool that has already been shutdown.

[Please note this exception arises only on Dev mode.]

I am using Play 2.2.1 on my local PC (Windows), and I am trying to schedule 2 jobs on app startup: a) schedule a job to run every 15 mins b) schedule a job to run on every midnight
I am using Akka system to schedule these jobs on app startup.

overriding Global.java for startup hook & delegate to helper

```
Global.java
    @Override
    public void onStart(Application app) {
    // schedule jobs
    job.JobScheduler.scheduleJobs();
}
```

perform actual scheduling here

```
    JobScheduler.java
        public static void scheduleJobs() {
                // schedule first job - every 15 mins
                Akka.system().scheduler().schedule(
            Duration.create(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
            Duration.create(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES), 
                        new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // some DB stuffs here
                }
            }, Akka.system().dispatcher());


               // schedule second job - every midnight
               Akka.system().scheduler().schedule... more code & DB stuffs
        }
```

But I am getting below exception stack trace on app startup:

```
[error] javax.persistence.PersistenceException: java.sql.SQLException: Attempting to [error]obtain a connection from a pool that has already been shutdown
[error]    .
[error]   Stack trace of location where pool was shutdown follows:
[error]     java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Unknown Source)
[error]     com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.captureStackTrace(BoneCP.java:543)
[error]     com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.shutdown(BoneCP.java:159)
...
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong.. thanks in advance.

Comment: I would assume that there is something wrong in your job, not the scheduling of them. It's a `SQLException` and you should focus on the code that does the database stuff.

Comment: Thanks, but the same code works fine in Prod mode. Also, the DB stuffs are simple CRUD operations that work fine from within the web context. Things I noticed in logs:                                           Starting application default Akka system.                           Shutdown application default Akka system.                          Exception when second job is being scheduled that involves DB stuffs